# By how much do the Thrifty Hacker and Vending Expert gene tonics lower vending machine prices, and how do they stack with each other?

Tags: bioshock-2

The [Vending Expert](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/BioShock_2_Gene_Tonics#Vending_Expert) gene tonic is described as "provides a slight reduction to prices in vending machines" while its upgrade, the Vending Expert 2 gene tonic is described as "provides a substantial reduction to prices in vending machines".

The [Thrifty Hacker](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/BioShock_2_Gene_Tonics#Thrifty_Hacker) gene tonic's effects is described as "hacked vending prices are even cheaper".

By how much do the Vending Expert 1 or 2, and the Thrifty Hacker gene tonics lower vending machine prices? If a vending machine is hacked, how do the Vending Expert 1 or 2, and Thrifty Hacker stack with each other if both gene tonics are equipped?

Answer (score 2):

**Hacking** a machine takes **20%** off the price of most items.

**Thrifty Hacker** provides **10%** off prices, but only when the machine is hacked.

**Vending Expert** provides **10%** off hacked or unhacked prices.

**Vending Expert 2** provides **15%** off hacked or unhacked prices.

*The effect of the tonics is **additive** with each other, but **multiplicative** with the discount provided by hacking.*

To calculate the final cost of an item, use the following formulas.

```
Base_cost = Base cost of item.  This is the unhacked cost with no tonics.

Tonic_Discount = Sum of all discounts from tonics, per above
  up to (35%) for all three vending tonics

Hacking_Multiplier = 100 if the machine is unhacked.
                   = 80 if the machine is hacked.

Final_Cost = Base_cost * (Hacking_Multiplier / 100) * (100 - Tonic_Discount) / 100
```

The best possible price from a hacked vending machine with all three tonics is **52%** of the base price of the item.

If you only splice one tonic, the best choice is *Vending Expert 2*, followed by *Vending Expert*.  *Thrifty Hacker* is the least useful of the three, because while it provides exactly the same discount as *Vending Expert*, it only works on hacked machines.